# Can't remove an element in XML

Tags: c#, html, xml, linq, xelement

I have XElement xDoc =

```
<div id="item123">
    <div id="item456">
        <h3 id="1483538342">
           <span>Dessuten møtte</span> 
        </h3>
        <p>Test!</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to remove en item with id = "item456" I get an error

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

var item = "456";
xDoc.Descendants("div").Where(s => s.Attribute("id").Value == "item" + item).Remove();
```

I can't understand what is wrong here.

Comment: `"item" + item` will search for attribute value `"itemitem456"`.

Comment: Your xml looks like html...

Comment: Adriano, it was wrong typed. Now it is fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: Sergey, html is one kind of XML. The problem is not here.

Comment: @podeig not exactly - xml is case-sensitive and it does not allow not-closed tags. So, valid html can be invalid xml, and parsing will fail. And I didn't say that is a problem in your sample. I just suggesting to use right tool for right data (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the current element (inside the `where` iteration) has an `id` attribute, otherwise you will access a null object and get an exception.

```
var item = "456";
xDoc.Descendants("div").Where(s => s.Attribute("id") != null && s.Attribute("id").Value == "item" + item).Remove();
```

Comment: It looks that you are right. I do not get the exception any more. But this element is stil there. It is not removed.

Comment: Is the element still in the `xdoc` object or are you talking about a file where it gets persisted? You can check if `Where` finds your targeted element by using `var elem = xDoc.Descendants("div").Where(s => s.Attribute("id") != null && s.Attribute("id").Value == "item" + item).FirstOrDefault();`. If `elem` is `null` your argument ("item456") might not be valid.

Comment: Everything is ok. Working!!! I checked the result at the wronf place. Thank you for help, Andrei! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your error means that some of `div` elements do not have `id` attribute. Thus `s.Attribute("id")` returns `null`. Trying to get it's value throws exception. If you will cast attribute to `string` instead of trying to access it's `Value`, you will not get error (`null` will be returned if attribute was not found):

```
xDoc.Descendants("div")
    .Where(d => (string)d.Attribute("id") == "item" + item)
    .Remove();
```

Also thus you are dealing with HTML I suggest you to use appropriate tool - [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Removing your div nodes will look like:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(path_to_file);
foreach (var div in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='item456']"))
    div.Remove();
```